# How can I make Perl and Python print each line of the program being executed?

Tags: python, bash, perl, debugging, trace

I know that `bash -x script.sh` will execute script printing each line before actual execution.
How to make Perl and Python interpreters do the same?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[Devel::Trace](http://search.cpan.org/~mjd/Devel-Trace-0.10/Trace.pm) is the Perl analogue, the [trace module](http://docs.python.org/library/trace.html) is Python's.

Comment: For clarification: `perl -d:Trace program.pl` and `python -m trace -t program.py` respectively.

Comment: @Vi.+1 for the command-line options for Devel::Trace.  
FWIW: For enabling perl debugging under apache mod_perl see the following link:http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=412121. Haven't tried it but it might help someone else.

Answer (score 12):

**`python -m trace -t main.py`**

Test program:

main.py

```
from a import g
def f(i):
    g(i)
for i in range(3):
    f(i)
```

a.py

```
def g(i):
    print i
```

Output:

```
 --- modulename: main, funcname: <module>
main.py(1): from a import g
 --- modulename: a, funcname: <module>
a.py(1): def g(i):
main.py(2): def f(i):
main.py(4): for i in range(3):
main.py(5):     f(i)
 --- modulename: main, funcname: f
main.py(3):     g(i)
 --- modulename: a, funcname: g
a.py(2):     print i
0
main.py(4): for i in range(3):
main.py(5):     f(i)
 --- modulename: main, funcname: f
main.py(3):     g(i)
 --- modulename: a, funcname: g
a.py(2):     print i
1
main.py(4): for i in range(3):
main.py(5):     f(i)
 --- modulename: main, funcname: f
main.py(3):     g(i)
 --- modulename: a, funcname: g
a.py(2):     print i
2
main.py(4): for i in range(3):
 --- modulename: trace, funcname: _unsettrace
trace.py(80):         sys.settrace(None)
```

Tested on Ubuntu 16.10, Python 2.7.12.

Comment: This seems redundant to the other answers to the question.

Comment: @duskwuff thanks for feedback. It saves a click and finding that you need `-t`, and shows what you get on a minimal multi-file example.

Comment: It's better to have the answer in the question rather than a linked document if it's practical, not just for convenience, also to avoid link rot.

Answer (score 7):

[`Devel::DumpTrace`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::DumpTrace) was released in 2011 and has more features than `Devel::Trace`, such as evaluating variable values in the trace output.