# Is there a way to turn on tracing in perl (equivalent to bash -x)?

Tags: perl, debugging, trace

I have a system script in perl. I need some equivalent of bash -x to determine what is going wrong with the script. Is there something equivalent?

EDIT: What bash -x does is that it prints each line as it is evaluated. This makes debugging code that is just missing some path variable or file very easy.

Comment: Explain what you want to do in terms of what you're wanting to do. Not in terms of specific arbitrary shell.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make Perl and Python print each line of the program being executed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872089/how-can-i-make-perl-and-python-print-each-line-of-the-program-being-executed)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are some good Perl debugging methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037583/what-are-some-good-perl-debugging-methods)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Take a look at [`Devel::Trace`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-Trace/Trace.pm) or [`Devel::ebug`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-ebug/lib/Devel/ebug.pm).

Given this program named `w.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $answer = 42;

if ($answer == 6 * 9) {
    print "everything is running fine.\n";
} else {
    warn "there must be a bug somewhere...\n";
}
```

You can use `Devel::Trace` to watch the execution:

```
perl -d:Trace w.pl
```

Which produces the following output:

```
>> w.pl:6: my $answer = 42;
>> w.pl:8: if ($answer == 6 * 9) {
>> w.pl:11:     warn "there must be a bug somewhere...\n";
there must be a bug somewhere...
```

Comment: This worked: PERLDB_OPTS="NonStop AutoTrace" perl -d ./trial.pl

Comment: Of course you need to install the module fist: `sudo cpan install "Devel::Trace"`.

Answer (score 9):

The [`Devel::DumpTrace`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::DumpTrace) module has been available since 2011.

Sample usage:

```
$ cat demo.pl
# demo.pl
# a demonstration of Devel::DumpTrace
$a = 1;
$b = 3;
$c = 2 * $a + 7 * $b;
@d = ($a, $b, $c + $b);

$ perl -d:DumpTrace demo.pl
>>>>> demo.pl:3:        $a:1 = 1;
>>>>> demo.pl:4:        $b:3 = 3;
>>>>> demo.pl:5:        $c:23 = 2 * $a:1 + 7 * $b:3;
>>>>> demo.pl:6:        @d:(1,3,26) = ($a:1, $b:3, $c:23 + $b:3);
```

Answer (score 7):

You should look at "perl -d" (turn on debugger) or "perl -c" (check your script before executing

Comment: Be warned, "before executing" doesn't mean no code runs.  Any code in a `BEGIN` block (or in a module than has been included with `use`) will run even if you use the `-c` option: `perl -cle 'BEGIN { print "oops, this runs" } print "but this does not"'`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running a current version of perl you can use Devel::Agent.

```
perl -d:Agent -MDevel::Agent::EveryThing myscript.pl
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Always include these statements in your perl scripts:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

If you want to debug it, use the `-d` switch. And here are the commands: http://www.domainavenue.com/pl-debug.htm

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the Perl debugger (run your program by prefixing `perl -d`  to it) you can use the `t` (*trace*) command in the interactive debugger to toggle tracing.
After reloading your program (`R`) the status of the trace is reset.
Unfortunately tracing can significantly slow down your program, especially if loops are executed many times.

Here is some example output:

```perl
...
Digest::HMAC::new(/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.18.2/Digest/HMAC.pm:10):
10:         my($class, $key, $hasher, $block_size) =  @_;
Digest::HMAC::new(/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.18.2/Digest/HMAC.pm:11):
11:         $block_size ||= 64;
Digest::HMAC::new(/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.18.2/Digest/HMAC.pm:12):
12:         $key = $hasher->new->add($key)->digest if length($key) > $block_size;
Digest::HMAC::new(/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.18.2/Digest/HMAC.pm:14):
14:         my $self = bless {}, $class;
Digest::HMAC::new(/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.18.2/Digest/HMAC.pm:15):
15:         $self->{k_ipad} = $key ^ (chr(0x36) x $block_size);
Digest::HMAC::new(/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.18.2/Digest/HMAC.pm:16):
16:         $self->{k_opad} = $key ^ (chr(0x5c) x $block_size);
Digest::HMAC::new(/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.18.2/Digest/HMAC.pm:17):
17:         $self->{hasher} = $hasher->new->add($self->{k_ipad});
Digest::SHA::new(/usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Digest/SHA.pm:45):
45:             my($class, $alg) = @_;
...
```

Comment: BTW: Does anybody know a way to restrict tracing to specific subroutines only (to reduce the slow-down)?