# "sh -x" equivalent for Perl and Python scripts

Tags: perl, shell, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make Perl and Python print each line of the program being executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872089/how-can-i-make-perl-and-python-print-each-line-of-the-program-being-executed)

I'm looking for an equivalent of `sh -x` for Perl and Python.

Comment: See [this][1] previous question 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872089/how-can-i-make-perl-and-python-print-each-line-of-the-program-being-executed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872089/how-can-i-make-perl-and-python-print-each-line-of-the-program-being-executed

Asked previously

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install [Devel::Trace](http://metacpan.org/module/Devel::Trace) and `perl -d:Trace`.

Answer (score 7):

(Excerpted from *Programming Perl*’s chapter on the debugger.)

If your `.perldb` file contains:

```
parse_options("NonStop=1 LineInfo=tperl.out AutoTrace");
```

then your program will run without human intervention, putting trace
information into the file `tperl.out`.  (If you interrupt it, you’d better
reset `LineInfo` to `/dev/tty` if you expect to see anything.)